# Optimizing slow SQL query: derived tables and two different joins based on row type

Tags: sql, query-optimization, firebird, firebird2.1

I'm using Firebird 2.1. I'd like to optimize the following query as it executes really slowly (almost 2 secs) on even a small dataset (cca 500 records):

TABLE Client stores persons and companies/company groups. (ClientType=0 person, ClientType=1 company) Primary key: ClientID

TABLE ClientContacts stores which persons are linked to which companies: ClientID is the company's ID, ContactClientID is the person's ID linked to the company. Primary keys: ClientID, ContactClientID

TABLE CompanyGroups stores which companys are linked to which company groups: ParentClientID is the company group's ID, ClientID is the company's ID attached to the company group. Primary keys: ParentClientID, ClientID

So a person may belong to more than one company, and a company may belong to more than one company groups.

I would like to list all persons and companys. For persons I want to show which companies it belongs to, and for companys I want to show which company groups the company belongs to.

To top it, I need to search by the name of the companies/company groups to which the person/company belongs. In Firebird because of aggregate function "LIST" I can achieve this with derived tables.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT C.ClientID,
  C.ClientType,
  C.ClientName,
  IIF(C.ClientType = 0, PCN.PCompanyNames, CCN.CCompanyNames),
FROM Clients C
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT CC.ContactClientID, LIST(CL.ClientName, ', ') AS PCompanyNames
   FROM ClientContacts CC LEFT JOIN Clients CL ON CL.ClientID = CC.ClientID WHERE 
    CL.AccessRights = 0 OR CL.UserID = :UserID OR (CL.AccessRights = 2 AND 
     CL.ClientID IN (SELECT ClientID FROM ClientRights WHERE UserID = :UserID))
      GROUP BY CC.ContactClientID) PCN ON PCN.ContactClientID = C.ClientID AND C.ClientType = 0
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT CG.ClientID, LIST(CL.ClientName, ', ') AS CCompanyNames
   FROM CompanyGroups CG LEFT JOIN Clients CL ON CL.ClientID = CG.ParentClientID WHERE 
    CL.AccessRights = 0 OR CL.UserID = :UserID OR (CL.AccessRights = 2 AND
     CL.ClientID IN (SELECT ClientID FROM ClientRights WHERE UserID = :UserID))
      GROUP BY CG.ClientID) CCN ON CCN.ClientID = C.ClientID AND C.ClientType = 1
WHERE (C.AccessRights = 0
    OR C.UserID = :UserID
      OR (C.AccessRights = 2 AND C.ClientID IN (SELECT ClientID FROM ClientRights WHERE UserID = :UserID)))
  AND (:SearchStr IS NULL
    OR (PCN.PCompanyNames COLLATE UNICODE_CI LIKE '%' || :SearchStr || '%'
    OR CCN.CCompanyNames COLLATE UNICODE_CI LIKE '%' || :SearchStr || '%'))
```

---

*Update* Query plan, first the above query, second the above query without the WHERE clauses everywhere (no IN SELECT)

```
Field #01: CLIENTS.CLIENTID Alias:CLIENTID Type:INTEGER
Field #02: CLIENTS.CLIENTTYPE Alias:CLIENTTYPE Type:INTEGER
Field #03: CLIENTS.CLIENTNAME Alias:CLIENTNAME Type:STRING(1000)
Field #04: .CASE Alias:CASE Type:BLOB SUB_TYPE 1
PLAN (PCN CLIENTRIGHTS INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY46))
PLAN (CCN CLIENTRIGHTS INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY46))
PLAN (CLIENTRIGHTS INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY46))
PLAN JOIN (JOIN (C INDEX (IDX_CLIENTS_ACCESSRIGHTS, IDX_CLIENTS_USERID, IDX_CLIENTS_ACCESSRIGHTS), SORT (JOIN (PCN CC NATURAL, PCN CL INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY12)))), SORT (JOIN (CCN CG NATURAL, CCN CL INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY12))))

119643 fetches, 0 marks, 0 reads, 0 writes.
0 inserts, 0 updates, 0 deletes, 19977 index, 19629 seq.
Delta memory: 321686664 bytes.
Total execution time: 1.531s


Field #01: CLIENTS.CLIENTID Alias:CLIENTID Type:INTEGER
Field #02: CLIENTS.CLIENTTYPE Alias:CLIENTTYPE Type:INTEGER
Field #03: CLIENTS.CLIENTNAME Alias:CLIENTNAME Type:STRING(1000)
Field #04: .CASE Alias:CASE Type:BLOB SUB_TYPE 1
PLAN JOIN (JOIN (C NATURAL, SORT (JOIN (PCN CC NATURAL, PCN CL INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY12)))), SORT (JOIN (CCN CG NATURAL, CCN CL INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY12))))

119289 fetches, 0 marks, 0 reads, 0 writes.
0 inserts, 0 updates, 0 deletes, 19646 index, 19832 seq.
Delta memory: 321690896 bytes.
Total execution time: 1.406s
```

Comment: Please show the DDL of the tables involved, including all index. Also post the current plan of the query. One of the things that jumps out immediately is the use of an `IN (select ...)`, replacing that with an `exists` query usually performs better. But the performance killer is probably the use of the usage of `LIKE` to search inside text fields.

Comment: Mark, taking out the "IN (SELECT)" and "LIKE" doesn't improve the perfomance (as I was testing it with SearchStr = NULL and AccessRights is 0 almost everywhere in Clients). I'll post more.

Comment: OK, so I've added the query plan, plus the primary keys, there are no other used indices

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on the firebird-support mailinglist as well. It might get a better response.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I can't place comment (there is no needed reputation). It's difficult to do without structure, but I try.

So:

1) You need devide your query into two parts exactly: ClientType = 0 and ClientType = 1;

2) You don't need left join inside PCN and CCN, because it makes no sense;

3) You have often used query:

```
select ClientID
from Client
where c.AccessRight = 0 or
      c.UserId = :UserId or
      (c.AccessRight = 2 and
       c.ClientId in (
          select r.ClientId
          from ClientRights r
          where r.UserId = :UserId))
```

I think you should do something like this:

```
with
cl as (
   select c.ClientId, c.ClientName, c.ClientType
   from Client c
   where c.AccessRight = 0 or
         c.UserId = :UserId or
         (c.AccessRight = 2 and c.ClientId in (select r.ClientId from ClientRights r where r.UserId = :UserId))),
q2 as (
    select cc.ContactClientId, List (cl.ClientName, ', ') as PCompanyNames
    from ClientContacts cc
         join cl on (cc.ClientId = cl.ClientId)
    group by cc.ContactClientId),
q3 as (
    select cg.ClientId, List (cl.ClientName, ', ') as CCompanyNames
    from CompanyGroups cg
         join cl on (cg.ParentClientId = cl.ClientId)
    group by cg.ClientId)
select cl.ClientId, cl.ClientType, cl.ClientName, q2.PCompanyNames
from cl
     left join q2 on (cl.ClientId = q2.ContactClientId)
where cl.ClientType = 0
  and (q2.PCompanyNames like '%' || Coalesce (:SearchStr, '') || '%' or Coalesce(:SearchStr, '') = '')
union all
select cl.ClientId, cl.ClientType, cl.ClientName, q3.CCompanyNames
from cl
     left join q3 on (cl.ClientId = q3.ClientId)
where cl.ClientType = 1
  and (q3.CCompanyNames like '%' || Coalesce (:SearchStr, '') || '%' or Coalesce(:SearchStr, '') = '')
```

Comment: Thanks, your query is super fast, executes in under 0,2 secs! The only thing is that I need to order the result set by Clientname. Putting the order by clause in your query slows down the execution time to 4 secs. With my query the execution time is the same if you put in the order by. Any ideas on how to optimize your query with the order by clause?

Comment: Can you create index by ClientName? And write here timing.

Comment: It's not any faster with the index, similarly around 4 seconds. Any other ideas?